# when call TransactionScope.Dispose() throw an "Aborted transaction" exception

Tags: c#, oracle

I have an operation to insert data to 32-bit Oracle database(10.2.0.1.0),when call Dispose() throw an "Aborted transaction" abnormal,but the data is successful insertion.Do the same operation on the 64-bit oracle database but does not appear abnormal.

```
var option = new TransactionOptions();
option.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
option.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);
TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, option);
using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=        (PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.116.222)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=orcl)));User     ID=strong;Password=strong;"))
    {
        string sqlStr = "INSERT into TEST_USER (CreateTime)values(sysdate)";
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = sqlStr;
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
scope.Complete();
scope.Dispose();
```

Comment: Read the Remarks part in this page - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.dispose(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I have read the Reamarks,but why insert data to 32-bit Oracle database(11.1.0.6.0) or 64-bit Oracle database or sql server database ,won't appear the abnormal

Comment: Transaction triggered six events that found in tracking log. TRANSACTION_BEGUN->                            RM_ENLISTED_IN_TRANSACTION->       RECEIVED_COMMIT_REQUEST_FROM_BEGINNER->                  RM_VOTED_ABORT->                                   TRANSACTION_ABORTING->  TRANSACTION_ABORTED